# how to convert javascript code to html code

Tags: javascript, html

i got this code that i want to make work in tumblr but that is html code and this is javascript? i am a noob maybe someone can help me out here.

```
<pre><code>


var total = 0;

function adder() {
  var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("myform").elements["num1"].value);
  var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("myform").elements["num2"].value);
  total += num1 + num2;
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = total;
  if (total > 100) console.log("It's over!");
}`









<form id="myform">
  First Number: <input type="text" name="num1"><br /><br /> Second Number: <input type="text" name="num2"><br /><br />
</form>
<button onclick="adder()"> Submit</button><br><br>
<p id="p1">Results Are Here</p>

</code></pre>
```

Comment: In the code provided they are closely linked - they are not interchangable. You cannot simply convert Javascript to HTML - that makes no sense - Javascript is permitting user interaction with the HTML in this case. You cannot accomplish the functionality of the javascript in pure HTMl alone

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try <xmp></xmp> tags for showing code with html tags.

<pre><code>


var total = 0;

function adder() {
  var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("myform").elements["num1"].value);
  var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("myform").elements["num2"].value);
  total += num1 + num2;
  document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = total;
  if (total > 100) console.log("It's over!");
}`


<xmp>
<form id="myform">
  First Number: <input type="text" name="num1"><br /><br /> Second Number: <input type="text" name="num2"><br /><br />
</form>
<button onclick="adder()"> Submit</button><br><br>
<p id="p1">Results Are Here</p>
</xmp>
</code></pre>
```